# How to reconfigure a Cosmos database to have shared container throughput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a database with several containers which have their own configured throughput. There is a new Cosmos DB feature which [allows all containers within a database to share throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database). I can create a new database which has this feature enabled, however I cannot seem to change my existing database to leverage this feature. Is there a way to enable this feature on an existing database, or do I have to create a new database and migrate all containers to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new database. Changing the existing database is not supported:

> A container with provisioned throughput cannot be converted to shared database container. Conversely a shared database container cannot be converted to have a dedicated throughput.

[Set throughput on a database and a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#set-throughput-on-a-database-and-a-container)